# How can i reconstruct this dataset so i can compare these two companies?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have this table:

| company | store type | year | average_spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | food | y1 | 123.4 |
| B | food | y2 | 340 |
| A | food | y3 | 9.4 |
| A | pharmacy | y1 | 13.4 |
| B | pharmacy | y2 | 90 |

There are two companies, 100 store types, and 3 years. I want to compare companies A and B YoY by average spend according to store type. I am unsure as to how i can pivot this table somehow but at same time perform no calculation. e.g it would be ideal to have store type as rows, with year *and* company as column headers as you  could do in excel. Only thing is by exporting the above table to excel the calclution has to be pefrmed when you pivot.

e.g. when i say column headers are year and company it would be year1 then under this company A | company B. ... unsure how to do this 'pivot'. Doing the below pivot would achieve what i want structurally however i don't want an aggfunction...

```
df.pivot_table(values='average_spend', index='store_type', columns=['company','year'], aggfunc='sum')
```

how could i do this?

```
company      A               B      
cols        y1     y2   y3    y1    y2    y3
food        123.4  NaN  9.4   10    340   NaN
pharmacy    13.4   NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df["company"].unique(), df["year"].unique()], names=["company", "year"]
)

x = df.pivot(
    values="average_spend", index="store_type", columns=["company", "year"]
)
x = x.reindex(columns=idx)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
company         A            B           
year           y1  y2   y3  y1     y2  y3
store_type                               
food        123.4 NaN  9.4 NaN  340.0 NaN
pharmacy     13.4 NaN  NaN NaN   90.0 NaN
```